# Check with PHP if a file is encrypted

Tags: php, encryption

I have a form that uploads a file via PHP to my server.

For security I analyze these files with ClamAV, however, encrypted files (eg.: zip with password, pdf with password) cannot be analyzed.

I tried via fopen to see if there was any error reading the file, but it reads the file normally, displaying the encrypted content without triggering errors.

Is it possible via PHP to detect if this file is encrypted and display an error message to the user?

Comment: It's not possible to detect all encryption methods -- the user could have a custom encryption algorithm that no one has ever heard of.

Comment: This is a good point, @Barmar

Comment: Barmar is correct, this is not possible completely. But @icekson has a solution that is going to be as close as you can practically get. I would add that you might want to proceed by asking yourself the question of why you are scanning these files, what the purpose of the uploads are. In many cases it makes the most sense to restrict uploads to a narrow set of types. Also, if you notice that most of the encrypted files are of a limited set of types (like password-protected zip or pdf) you could at least detect the most common such types. Ask yourself: which direction would you rather err in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each file type can be identified by first bites (file signature), here is the list of most used file types https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures. You can check the uploaded file type by this signature and if it's unknown then trigger an error for the user